# Audit history of record field changes

Tags: mysql, database, model-view-controller, database-design

I have a question about the database design for a project I am doing for my software dev course.

I have a table to store 'Purchase Orders' and each purchase order has a many-to-one relationship with a 'status' table. So, each purchase order can have a status, such as: "open request", "goods received", "invoice received" etc etc.

Well, that all works fine; however, I wish to store a history of the changes to the status field. So when it was changed to 'goods received' and when it was changed to 'invoice received' or any other status.

I imagine I need to create a new table to store these? If so, I am unsure how to implement this and, how I can build the required logic into my web application. I am learning everything from scratch, so I'm not sure If this logic should be in the controller of my laravel project (MVC) or if the database is capable of handling this - such as it is capable of cascade deleting records when a master record is deleted.

My main issue is I don't know if this type of problem has a name, so I am struggling to google it too.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable you might take a look at this library for a good example on how it should work.

Comment: Do you want just the current "status"?  (Use same table.)  Or a blow-by-blow of all the changes to "status"?  (Use different table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to create an audit/history trail of the Order based on its 'Status'.
From the database perspective alone, this is ONE way to achieve what you're looking for:

1. Create a new table say, OrderStatusLog --> With columns:
   a. OrderID (Primary Key from Orders table) - TO know which order it relates to
   b. Prev_OrderStatusID - This will be Old/Original Order Status
   c. Current_OrderStatsID - This will have the most recent OrderStatusID
2. Create a trigger on the Orders table such as:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgOrderStatusLog] 
   ON [dbo].[Orders]
   AFTER UPDATE   

   -- If you need to log when initially the Order was placed, change the 
   above line to:  
   -- AFTER INSERT,UPDATE 

   AS 

   INSERT INTO OrderStatusLog(OrderID, Prev_OrderStatusID, Current_OrderStatsID)

   SELECT           
     I.ORDERID,
     D.OrderStatusID, -- This is your Order Status before update
     I.OrderStatusID  -- This is your Order Status before update
   FROM INSERTED I 
   INNER JOIN DELETED D ON I.ORDERID = D.ORDERID
   ```
3. A good idea would be to add Timestamp and User updating the record (Even for the school project).
4. From this point, all you need is an update call/procedure that will be updating the Orders table.  And, a log/record for each update would be created in the `OrderStatusLog` table.

This is a very basic and straight forward of achieving the task at hand.  Also, this syntax was based on SQL Server.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple methods for history logging or you can say Audit logging.

```
1.Triggers
2.CDC(IN SQL server only)
3. By Your own code (i.e object cloning)
4. Inside your DML procedures
```

Answer (score 2):

> *My main issue is I don't know if this type of problem has a name, so I am struggling to google it too.*

What you're looking for is "audit" or "audit log" or "versioning".

I like how [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) does it. You have one table to store changes to any table. The audit table stores the table, primary key, action (insert, update, delete), and a snapshot of the row as [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html).

You can either implement this as [database triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html) or as callbacks in your ORM.